# RDLC REPORT Justify in VS2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I use RDLC report in VS 2012, I'm facing alignment problem, help in this regard, I can only find left, right, center, **I need to align text justify in textbox**, how can I do this?

> Alignment in VS 2012 RDLC report, justify

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is not possible with SSRS (still - it's only been on your radar for 8 years, Microsoft).

If you want to do a lot of extra work to accomplish it, you can try:

http://knackbi.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this function using the list of strings with any same-width font, like courier new.

```
        public static List<string> GetText(string text, int width)
    {
        string[] palabras = text.Split(' ');
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
        int length = palabras.Length;
        List<string> resultado = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            sb1.AppendFormat("{0} ", palabras[i]);
            if (sb1.ToString().Length > width)
            {
                resultado.Add(sb2.ToString());
                sb1 = new StringBuilder();
                sb2 = new StringBuilder();
                sb1.AppendFormat("{0} ", palabras[i]);
                sb2.AppendFormat("{0} ", palabras[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                sb2.AppendFormat("{0} ", palabras[i]);
            }
        }
        resultado.Add(sb2.ToString());

        List<string> resultado2 = new List<string>();
        string temp;

        int index1, index2, salto;
        string target;
        int limite = resultado.Count;
        foreach (var item in resultado)
        {
            target = " ";
            temp = item.ToString().Trim();
            index1 = 0; index2 = 0; salto = 2;

            if (limite <= 1)
            {
                resultado2.Add(temp);
                break;
            }
            while (temp.Length <= width)
            {
                if (temp.IndexOf(target, index2) < 0)
                {
                    index1 = 0; index2 = 0;
                    target = target + " ";
                    salto++;
                }
                index1 = temp.IndexOf(target, index2);
                temp = temp.Insert(temp.IndexOf(target, index2), " ");
                index2 = index1 + salto;

            }
            limite--;
            resultado2.Add(temp);
        }
        return resultado2;
    }
```