# How to justify text on an RDLC report on C#

Tags: c#, world-coordinates

I'm trying to justify the text inside a RLDC report text-box in C#.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135044/rdlc-report-justify-in-vs2012) but couldn't make it work.

This is what I've got inside the expression:

```html
="<div style='text-align: justify; text-justify: inter-character;'>La empresa " +First(Fields!name.Value, "CompanyCertificate")+ " identificada con el Nit. " +First(Fields!documentNumber.Value, "CompanyCertificate")+ " se encuentra afiliada en la Caja de Compensación Familiar del Valle del Cauca - Comfamiliar Andi - Comfandi.</div>"
```

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etEwq.png)

This is the PDF it generates, but the main text is left aligned, and I need it justified:

[See pdf screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmGU5.png)

Is that html code wrong? How could I make this work?

Comment: Try to add the width as well to see if this works, like <div style='text-align: justify; text-justify: inter-character; width:600px'>